# String from plist not standard string? Crash app using string from plist. iOS

Tags: ios, nsstring, cocos2d-iphone, plist

Sorry for long post.
String from plist crash my program when i using it in the second time.
I have cocos2d project ([attach](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/15739872/myzip.zip)) with one scene and one object. And one .plist file

```
HelloWorldLayer.h & .m (instantiate from CCLayer) 
NodeObject.h & .m (instantiate from CCNode)
Test.plist
```

In **NodeObject** i have one local string and two method

```
@interface NodeObject : CCNode
{
    NSString *stringForPrint;
}
-(void)createObjWithString:(NSString *)string;
-(void)printString;
```

In this both method we print string obtained in parameter *string*

```
-(void)createObjWithString:(NSString *)string
{
    stringForPrint = string;
    NSLog(@"NodeObject.createObjWithString stringForPrint >> %@", stringForPrint);
}

-(void)printString
{
    NSLog(@"NodeObject.printString stringForPrint >> %@", stringForPrint);
}
```

Plis content is one array with one dictionary whit item type string.

```
Root 
-TestArray <Array>
--item 0 <Dictionary>
---type <String> == "This is string from plist"
```

For test, into the scene i'm create **NodeObject** and get dada from plist. And print this string. It's work correctly.

```
if ([testDictionary objectForKey:@"TestArray"]) {
            for (NSDictionary *tempItemData in [testDictionary objectForKey:@"TestArray"]) {
                NSLog(@"type form plist in for loop > %@", [tempItemData objectForKey:@"type"]);//It's cool work. True string from plist.
            }
        }
```

I create my **NodeObject** into the loop. And it's work again.

```
if ([testDictionary objectForKey:@"TestArray"]) {
            for (NSDictionary *tempItemData in [testDictionary objectForKey:@"TestArray"]) {
                NodeObject *testObj = [NodeObject node];
                //and send it string from plist 
                [testObj createObjWithString:[tempItemData objectForKey:@"type"]];
            }
        }
```

BUT! if i have tried use this string in the **printString** method form **NodeObject**, app will crash without log.
[testObj printString]; //crash app

I repeat. Object creation with manual string work. If using string from plist it's crash.
I broke my head. And only in the second method. In the **createObjWithStrig** it work.

```
    //Work
    NodeObject *testObj = [NodeObject node];
    [testObj createObjWithString:@"manual string object"];
    [testObj printString]; // Print correct string

    //Crash
    NodeObject *testObj = [NodeObject node];
    [testObj createObjWithString:[tempItemData objectForKey:@"type"]];
    [testObj printString]; //Crash here
```

I'm attach [project file](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/15739872/myzip.zip). Can test this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Apple forum i found the answer.
Object i get out from plist is autoreleased. It's can not be just assigned and using later.

I should use retain or copy.

```
printString = [string retain];
```

solved this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can check what's hodden behinde the variable using `description` and `class` methods.

So try

`NSLog(@"Description  %@ and class %@",[[tempItemData objectForKey:@"type"]description],[[tempItemData objectForKey:@"type"]class]);`

This may give you some information on where the things go wrong - maybe it's null)

Comment: Hi and thanks for tip. This log say that object  class is __NSCFString. Avery wear i'm read about converting __NSCFString to NSString write that no reasons that do. But i have problem with __NSCFString and not have they with NSStribg. What do you think?